# Android xamarin MVVM device PM451 barcode scanner

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvm

have any of you written a PM451 scanner handler or similar to handle the barcode scanner read event call in android xamarin MVVM.  Unfortunately I am not able to handle this device. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Operation of a barcode scanner

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.

Comment: I think that is what you are looking for https://github.com/JimmyPun610/BarcodeScanner.Mobile

Comment: No he is talking about using an actual physical scanner.  Most of which function as a keyboard wedge and don't special programming, but its impossible to tell based on the limited information they posted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.